# Show html file in alertdilaog builder in Android

Tags: android, html

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setCancelable(false) // Cant Be Cancel By Pressing Back Key Only By Pressing Positive Button
                .setTitle("About")  // Can Also Be Done By HTML Style
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<i> etc etc stuff"))
                .create();
               d.show();
```

But I have html file in my raw folder which I want to display html file is properly formatted and I have put all the required escape sequences like etc stuff in html file which is in my raw folder

What I actually want is to display the html file in `.setMessage`. Like getResources().open something like this not working for me

How could I do it?

Comment: Please explain what "getresources().open something like this not working for me" means.

Comment: i got the answer bro check the ticked answer thats what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i used to use this code written above but i have html file in my raw
>   folder which i want to display html file is properly formatted and i
>   have put all the required escape sequences like etc stuff in html file
>   which is in my raw folder

you probably want to use a `WebView`:

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/your_file_name.html");
```

and instead of

`.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<i> etc etc stuff"))`

use

`.setView(webView)`

Comment: you know what bro this is what i was looking for perfectly show and perfectly formatted thanks and yea selected as answer may help someone in future  ;)